# Firestore query with where and orderBy returning null when using in Streams in Flutter App

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, google-cloud-firestore, flutter-streambuilder

I am trying to get some document and sort them but when I am doing it with .orderBy it is returning null. If I use only .where and don't use orderBy, it is working fine.

I want to get some documents in a collection name 'expenses'   sorted with date.  But when I am doing it with .where and .orderBy it is returning null. If I use only .where and don't use orderBy, it is working fine.

```
Stream<List<Expense>> getExpenseStream() {
    UserModel user;

    return firestore
        .collection('expenses')
        .where("usersList", arrayContains: auth.currentUser?.phoneNumber)
        .snapshots()
        .map((event) {
      List<Expense> expenseList = [];
      for (var i in event.docs) {
        expenseList.add(Expense.fromMap(i.data()));
      }

      return expenseList;
    });
// It worked correctly
```

The above code works perfect without sorting.

```
Stream<List<Expense>> getExpenseStream() {
    UserModel user;

    return firestore
        .collection('expenses')
        .where("usersList", arrayContains: auth.currentUser?.phoneNumber)
        .orderBy("date", descending: true)
        .snapshots()
        .map((event) {
      List<Expense> expenseList = [];
      for (var i in event.docs) {
        expenseList.add(Expense.fromMap(i.data()));
      }

      return expenseList;
    });
```

This code is returning null.

And as I can see in my App the function fetched data for a second and then returned null.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the problem starts when you add the `orderBy` instruction, it's likely because at that point Firestore needs a [composite index](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/index-overview#composite_indexes) to perform the query and (unlike single-field indexes) you have to create that explicitly yourself.

You might want to try catching and logging errors from the code accessing the database, as a missing index typically should give you an error message and that error message includes a link to the Firestore dashboard with all the necessary info for the index filled in already. For more on this, also see the documentation on [creating a missing index through an error message](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/indexing#create_a_missing_index_through_an_error_message).

Alternatively, you can create a new composite index with the necessary fields yourself. In that case you'll need an to first add the `usersList` field in ascending order, and then the `date` field in descending order. For more on this, also see the documentation on [creating a missing index manually](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/indexing#use_the_firebase_console)

Comment: I added composite key, but still getting the same error.